# Twitter Bootstrap Nesting Containers with background image - Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to nest containers with Twitter Bootstrap to achieve the following in this screen shot. In the PSD the bubble image height is 404px. I need this to look good across all devices, so responsiveness is a must and should scale accordingly without overwhelming the screen.Could somebody please point me in the right direction to nail the CSS down for this?

I have added what I've done so far in Bootstrap to make this happen but it is off and need to get the containers right. I've read that containers in bootstrap shouldn't be nested but "can be".

[image]

I have nested containers but can't seem to achieve what is in the screen shots with Bootstrap.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=".container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 top">
                TOP TRENDING STORY FOR AUGUST 21, 2019
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 bg-top">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                test 1

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                Test 2

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.top{

    background-color: #d42222;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:23px;
    text-align: center;

}

.bg-top{

    background:transparent url('../images/background-top.png') no-repeat center center /cover;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs some styling to get what you want; You can take a look at the left and right margins which are inserted by Bootstrap `.container` and may want to override them; to get closer to the image you shared, I added some top and bottom margins myself;

Complete **working snippet** below:

```css
.redBanner {
  background: red;
}

.redBanner p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.myExternalContainer {
  background-image: url("https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.myInternalContainer {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.innerMostContainer {
  margin: 10%;
}

.innerMostContainer button {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid myExternalContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 top redBanner">
      <p class="text-center">TOP TRENDING STORY FOR AUGUST 21, 2019</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container myInternalContainer">
    <h3 class="text-center"> medicare</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="innerMostContainer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 bg-top">
            <img src='https://www.akberiqbal.com/src/images/LinkedIn4.png' class='img-fluid' />
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-6">
                Author Name
                <br/> Published date
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-primary'>Read time</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```